# Removing new lines before empty blocks in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

I prefer [Allman-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_style#Allman_style) braces, for example:

```
if (foo)
{
    // magical prancing unicorn stuff
}
```

rather than:

```
if (foo) {
    // unmagical boring pony things
}
```

The Java formatter in Eclipse handles this pretty well, except for empty code blocks, which it formats like this:

```
SomeDefaultCtor()
{}
```

I'd like to use this special format for empty blocks instead:

```
SomeDefaultCtor() {}
```

Is there any way to tell Eclipse to leave braces on the same line when the braces surround an empty code block? So far, I can't see one:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell this is not (yet) possible in eclipse; you can specify when new lines should be inserted or not but the configuration on the braces takes priority. If you feel strongly about this and do not despise IDE annotations for this you could use:

```
@formatter:off
SomeDefaultCtor() {}
@formatter:on
```

These must be enabled in the eclipse formatter.

Comment: _"This is not (yet) possible in eclipse"_ `[citation needed]`

Comment: sorry, can't give you one but I was trying to do the same thing a few weeks ago; tried about anything but it's simply not possible. But your right, my quote is still presumptuous.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use AnyEdit plugin: http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/

It's a very flexible plugin which allows to set a variety of conversions and filters to better format your file.

Worth a look :-)

Comment: Do you have specific instructions on how I could use AnyEdit to get the Java format preferences to do what I want?

Comment: Oh, sorry mate, I've read it wrong - I thought you wanted to remove whitespaces, etc