# Eclipse: opening braces on a new line, except when they are empty

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

Someone asked this question a couple years ago and no one actually answered it.  Is it still impossible in eclipse to have opening braces on a new line, except when they are empty?

[Removing new lines before empty blocks in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871670/removing-new-lines-before-empty-blocks-in-eclipse)

Comment: Just because you don't like the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5871902/2970947) doesn't mean someone didn't answer it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only want to ever see Allman style code and save K&R style code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876617/only-want-to-ever-see-allman-style-code-and-save-kr-style-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this still isn't possible in Juno Service Release 2

Comment: I think you are right.  I have Kepler, but digging around the options, I cannot find anything.  Infact, the formatting doesn't even look like much has changed.

Comment: I agree.. I was surprised that my formatter options looked pretty much the same as that 3 year old post.